# How to display checkboxes in MVC with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to create a View with a ViewModel which includes many Checkboxes. I can list the checkboxes but I couldnt figure out the labels.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.colors.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.colors[i].CHECKED)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.colors[i].COLOR)           
}
```

the second line in the loop displays "COLOR" next to every checkbox. What is the proper way to display the value in x.color[i].COLOR?

Comment: `@Html.LabelFor(x => x.colors[i].CHECKED, Model.colors[i].COLOR)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter of `LabelFor()` should be the same as used for `EditorFor()` so the the label is associated with the controls (clicking on the label toggles the checked state of the checkbox). A second parameter can be provided for the 'display text'. [Refer documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg513581(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.colors.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.colors[i].CHECKED)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.colors[i].CHECKED, Model.colors[i].COLOR)     
}
```

Comment: I can get the checkboxes values when submitted but it doesnt give the ID of the checkboxes is null. lets say there are 10 checkboxes, I check only two of them. when the form is submitted, I can see the 2 of them checked but their ID's are null. How can I bind the ID of the checkboxes?

Comment: Not sure what your mean. Does typeof `colors` have a property `ID`? If so you would need to render a control for the ID property e.g. `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.colors[i].ID)`